# How do you do inline delegates in vb.net like c#?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create an inline delegate in vb.net like you can in c#?

For example, I would like to be able to do something inline like this:

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(delegate (MyObject m) { return m.X >= 10; });
```

only in VB and without having to do something like this

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(AddressOf GreaterOrEqaulToTen) 

Private Function GreaterOrEqaulToTen(ByVal m as MyObject)
    If m.x >= 10 Then 
         Return true
    Else
         Return False
    End If
End Function
```

-- edit --
I should have mentioned that I am still working in .net 2.0 so I won't be able to use lambdas.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(Function(m As MyObject) m.X >= 10)
```

See [Lambda Expressions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(Function(m) m.X >= 10)
```

This works in 3.5, not sure about the 2.0 syntax.

Comment: indeed but your superior type casting trumps me

Comment: Strictly speaking it isn't required but for myself, it is a little more readable since I don't have to think about what "m" is